# String Split using the '|' delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have string values and I want to remove last numbers from that string.
My data set is as below:

```
AAB|LG|-|AE|CPL|C|SS|M|1.25
AAB|GU|-|NT|GU|O|3TOL|S|1.00
BT|KK|-|KK|-|N|M|-|1
CCB|EX|-|CPL|-|N/A|M|-|1.0
```

I want to get the data set as below:

```
AAB|LG|-|AE|CPL|C|SS|M|
AAB|GU|-|NT|GU|O|3TOL|S|
BT|KK|-|KK|-|N|M|-|
CCB|EX|-|CPL|-|N/A|M|-|
```

Comment: So, each of those lines is ONE field in a row?

Comment: No Line by Line

Comment: I don't know what that means for SQL.  Are you saying those are 9 fields in a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(ModifiedString, LEN(ModifiedString) - CHARINDEX('|', REVERSE(ModifiedString)) + 1) 
  AS trimmed_string
FROM temp;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/WdTxDw8D

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself: *"A good answer explains the solution."*